# Вписать текст в svg без использования js

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

Необходимо, чтоб текст максимально заполнил svg как при `bacground-size: contain`. Размер родителя `svg` может динамически изменяться. Текст всегда однострочный. Сейчас используется такое решение с помощью js, но желательно сделать средствами самого svg.

```js
const $svg = document.querySelector(`svg`);
const $text = $svg.querySelector('text');
const $input = document.querySelector('input');

$input.addEventListener('input', e => {
  $text.textContent = e.target.value;
  const box = $text.getBBox();
  $svg.setAttribute('viewBox', `${box.x} ${box.y} ${box.width} ${box.height}`);
});

$input.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'))
```

```css
svg {
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 10em;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<svg preserveAspectRatio="xMaxYMid meet">
<text alignment-baseline="baseline" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle" fill="black"></text>
</svg>
<input type='text' value='Случайный текст'>
```

Comment: (в одном случае) svg это картинка а картинка может быть резиновой (в другом же) js - вполне валидная __часть svg__

Comment: в `svg` находится `text` и он не ведёт себя как картинка. И хоть `js` и валидная часть `svg` но от`$svg.setAttribute('viewBox', `${box.x} ${box.y} ${box.width} ${box.height}`);`  сильно мешает и хочется от него избавиться.

Comment: кто .........................